# Select end date

Tags: date, time, fullcalendar

When I select dates in Fullcalendar, the date ends at midnight. How can I change the default end date and time?. I want it to end only at 9:00 am of the selected date.

```
var startDate =$.fullCalendar.moment(start).format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm a');  // Create a clone
start.stripTime();        // The time should already be stripped but lets do a sanity check.
start.time('08:00:00');   // Set a default start time.
start.hasTime();

var endDate = $.fullCalendar.moment(end).format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm a');
end.stripTime();        // The time should already be stripped but lets do a sanity check.
end.time('09:00:00');
end.hasTime();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, days usually end at midnight :)

What you can do is to limit the time you display in fullCalendar.
You can do it setting the properties [minTime](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/minTime/) and [maxTime](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/maxTime/)

Something like:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    minTime: "08:00:00", // Duration object, default: "00:00:00"
    maxTime: "09:00:00"  // Duration object, default: "24:00:00"
});
```